# How to use the IN operation in a Simple expression?

Tags: apache-camel

I just wish to check the return code of a HTTP call against a list of values. The logical case would be to use the IN operator, but I can't seem to make it work.

The documentation says to use a comma delimited list of values to check against so I did this:

`header.CamelHttpResponseCode in 204,200`

but it does not seem to kick in. Anyone done this kind of thing?

Comment: Where exactly you have found such syntax? The correct syntax is `${in.header.CamelHttpResponseCode} in '204,200'` as documented https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html

Comment: I have read that documentation, could not see that it was documented like that. Must have overlooked something.

Comment: Ok, I was asking, because if this is documented this way somewhere, then it is wrong. If you find that, please let us know to fix this, or use `Edit this page` in top right corner of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single quotes around the status codes

`<simple>${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} in '204,200'</simple>`

Or in java dsl:

`.simple("${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} in '204,200' ")`

Comment: Thanks! This works, that was the piece of info I was missing.